# Autolayout - relationship between two objects, which is "dominant"?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, autolayout, constraints

Say I have two objects on the screen. I position one of them with constraints to be at the position and size I want it to be.

The other object's constraints are:

- Align Center X to Object 1
- Align Center Y to Object 1
- Equal Width to Object 1
- Equal Height to Object 1

So... why is Object 1 changing to meet the height/width of the second object and not the other way around - thereby also setting the positioning out of whack as well? I'm asking the second object to be at the size and location of Object 1 with those 4 constraints, am I not?

Thanks for any explanation!

**Edit:** Second object is a UIImageView with "Aspect Fit" set as the content mode. Object 1 is a UILabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All views need to get their height and width from somewhere. But you have not supplied either height or width for either view.

Both an image view and a label get their height and width from their `intrinsicContentSize` if you don't supply height / width constraints.

The `intrinsicContentSize` is translated into constraints at a priority determined by the [Content Hugging Priority](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622556-contenthuggingpriority) and the [Content Compression Resistance Priority](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622465-contentcompressionresistanceprio) for each axis.

If you look at those values for both views (in their size inspectors in the storyboard, or in code if you're creating them in code), you will see that either this is a stalemate or the image view has higher priorities and wins. Either way, you need to resolve the battle the way *you* want it resolved, by raising or lowering the priority for one of the views.

Comment: If you use the View Debugger on the app when it is running, this will all be much clearer. You might even see an exclamation mark and a warning that your layout is ambiguous.

Comment: Strange - both objects had horizontal/vertical content compression resistance priority at 750. Changing this to even 255 horizontal/vertical compression resistance priority on the UIImageView did not fix the issue, but changing it to 250 did. Thank you.